# How to pass information to window proc created using WinAPI

Tags: delphi, winapi

I needed to create a window for handling messages (WM_HOTKEY) so I went about going low level with the following and using SetWindowLong to pass the instance information for use in the windowproc.

```
fWindow:=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW,MsgWndClass.lpszClassName,'',WS_POPUP,0,0,0,0,0,0,HInstance,nil);
SetWindowLong(fWindow,GWL_USERDATA,NativeInt(Self));
```

and the windowproc is

```
class function TMessageWindow.WindowProc(hWnd: HWND; uMsg: Integer; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): Integer;
begin
  var I:=GetWindowLong(hWnd,GWL_USERDATA);
  if I=0 then
    Exit(DefWindowProc(hWnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam));

  Result:=TMessageWindow(I).HandleMessage(uMsg,wParam,lParam);
end;
```

My issues arise when I tried to create an inherited class from TMessageWindow with HandleMessage being virtual.
I found that although the HandleMessage function was overriden in the inherited class, the typecast of TMessageWindow(I) was calling the base method.

After searching around looking for an example of this I could not find any examples of people using the SetWindowLong function to pass information to the windowproc so am now thinking there must be a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, make sure your `class` method is also marked as `static` to remove the hidden `Self` parameter, and is using the `stdcall` calling convention, if you haven't already done so, eg:

```pascal
class function WindowProc(hWnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall; static;
```

After that, if you are compiling for 64bit, your code needs to use `(Get|Set)WindowLongPtr()` instead, eg:

```pascal
private
  fWindow: HWND;
```

```pascal
fWindow := ...;
SetWindowLongPtr(fWindow, GWLP_USERDATA, LONG_PTR(Self));
```

```pascal
class function TMessageWindow.WindowProc(hWnd: HWND; uMsg: Integer; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): Integer; stdcall;
begin
  var I := GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
  if I <> 0 then
    Result := TMessageWindow(I).HandleMessage(uMsg, wParam, lParam)
  else
    Result := DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
end;
```

Alternatively, use [`SetWindowSubclass()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-setwindowsubclass) instead, eg:

```pascal
private
  fWindow: HWND;
  class function SubclassWindowProc(hWnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM; uIdSubclass: UINT_PTR; dwRefData: DWORD_PTR): LRESULT; stdcall; static;
```

```pascal
uses
  ..., Commctrl;

fWindow := ...;
SetWindowSubclass(fWindow, @TMessageWindow.SubclassWindowProc, 1, DWORD_PTR(Self));
```

```pascal
class function TMessageWindow.SubclassWindowProc(hWnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM; uIdSubclass: UINT_PTR; dwRefData: DWORD_PTR): LRESULT; stdcall;
begin
  if uMsg = WM_NCDESTROY then
    RemoveWindowSubclass(hWnd, @TMessageWindow.SubclassWindowProc, uIdSubclass);
  Result := TMessageWindow(dwRefData).HandleMessage(uMsg, wParam, lParam);
  // have HandleMessage() call DefSubclassProc() for any unhandled messages...
end;
```

That being said, an easier way to create a message window with a virtual message procedure is to use the RTL's [`AllocateHWnd()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.AllocateHWnd) function instead, eg:

```pascal
private
  fWindow: HWND;
  procedure HandleMessage(var Message: TMessage); virtual;
```

```pascal
// to create the window:
fWindow := AllocateHWnd(HandleMessage);
// to destroy the window:
DeallocateHWnd(fWindow);
```

```pascal
procedure TMessageWindow.HandleMessage(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  with Message do
    Result := DefWindowProc(fWindow, Msg, WParam, LParam);
end;
```

Comment: Remy you are a star and I will remember AllocateHwnd for the future however I have now found out that registerhotkey is system wide and not what I need as I wanted an application wide hotkey without touching the mainform.  I have now opted to use a keyboard hook.